# Dispatch Gesture how to reproduce the result of pressing the back button

Tags: java, android

Through DispatchGesture, I need to somehow click on the back button, but do it programmatically, without clicking on the button or reproduce **finish()**, only in another app

I found a code that only [clicks on the given coordinates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39283640/how-does-the-api-24-accessibilityservice-dispatchgesture-method-work)

Thanks in advance:)

**UPDATE**
I found this: [Trigger back-button functionality on button click in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4649508/trigger-back-button-functionality-on-button-click-in-android), but I want to make a click from Service